# How can I execute some function when a Link is clicked in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I would like to send a event log to google analytics when `Link` item clicked. (It opens safari)
But `Link` doesn't have 'action' parameter like `Button`.
Is that possible?

```swift
 let link = URL(...)
 Link(destination: link) {
   Image(systemName: "safari")
 }
```

Comment: Why not just use `Button`?

Comment: @aheze I didn't know that how to open safari app within the `Button` action. But I found it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also try this using a button as @​aheze suggested:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.openURL) var openURL
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: openSesame) {
            Text("open url")
        }
    }
    
    func openSesame() {
        // do something here
        print("---> about to open duckduckgo ")
        openURL(URL(string: "https://duckduckgo.com/")!)
        // or/and do something here
        print("---> after openning duckduckgo ")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Button` ​could do the same thing 'Link' could do.

(Thanks ​`aheze`'s comment)

The full code is

```swift
struct ArticleDetailView: View {
   ​var article: Article
   ​
   ​var body: some View {
       ​WebView(url: article.link)
           ​.navigationTitle(article.title)
           ​.toolbar(content: {
               ​Button(action: {
                   ​let articleUrl = article.link
                   ​if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(articleUrl) {
                       ​UIApplication.shared.open(articleUrl)
                       ​Analytics.logEvent("SAFARI_OPENED", parameters: nil)
                   ​}
               ​}, label: {
                   ​Image(systemName: "safari")
               ​})
           ​})
           ​.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
           ​.padding(0.0)
           ​.onAppear(perform: {
               ​Analytics.logEvent("CONTENT_LOADED", parameters: nil)
           ​})
   ​}
}
```